# Cylinder with a cylinder inside rolling down inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, work, torque

I've been trying to solve a problem, and I had a look at the solution, which I find confusing.

A cylinder with a hole inside is rolling down an inclined plane with friction. Inside the cylinder there is a smaller one which has the same dimension of the inside hole, but there is no friction inside the cylinder.

Now, the solution explains that the big cylinder is rolling because there is friction, but since the smaller one inside is sliding (cause there is no friction inside the bigger cylinder), the total system is both translating and rotating. Is that correct?

Then, to compute the translational velocity, it says that since the cylinder has a pure rolling motion, the friction doesn't do any work. Isn't this contradictory? What is the motion of this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner cylinder doesn't affect the outer one because of the lack of friction. The only force on the outer cylinder is the friction with the inclined floor and the force due to gravity, so if floor-friction is large enough, the outer cylinder undergoes pure rolling motion.

Similarly, the outer cylinder doesn't affect the inner one. The only force on it is the force due to gravity, which acts at its center of mass, so the inner cylinder undergoes pure translation (since there's nothing to make it roll)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I thought I had to consider them together and consider the velocity of the inner cylinder as the velocity of the center of mass. In this way the whole cylinder would have had both an angular velocity and a translational velocity. Why is it not the case?